# Программа зависает и не выводит массив

Tags: c

Даны действительные числа a1, . . . , a20. Получить:
1. a20, a11, a19, a10, . . . , a10, a1;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i;
int const n = 20;
double a[n];
for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
printf("[a%d] ", i+1); 
scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
}
for (i=0; i<n/2; i+2){
    a[i] = a[n-i];
    a[i+1] = a[10-i]; 
}

for(i=0; i<20; ++i)
printf("%lf\n", a[i]); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чему равно (и где находится) `a[n-i]`, когда `i` равно `0`?

Comment: Допустим, у вас в массиве было 1 2 3 4... - после первой же итерации цикла вы **затираете** навечно 1 и 2, их уже в массиве нет... Намек понятен?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i = i + 2) {
```

Comment: Теперь программ работает, но выдает неверный результат. При вводе от 1 до 20 выдает. 0.000000
11.000000
19.000000
9.000000
17.000000
7.000000
15.000000
17.000000
13.000000
19.000000
11.000000
12.000000
13.000000
14.000000
15.000000
16.000000
17.000000
18.000000
19.000000
20.000000

Comment: @Deadler Я ответил на вопрос, почему программа зависает. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа. Возьмите карандаш и листок бумаги. Выполните Ваш код на бумаге шаг за шагом.